# how to measure the time taken by activities in android

Tags: android

> I am working on quiz type application and I want to calculate the time between some activities. for example, my level starts from activity A and ends at activity H. I want to calculate the time taken by all the activities. Can anyone please help me to count the time taken from the first activity to the ending activity?

Comment: Just record the time the user started and then calculate the difference to the time when the user has finished. It's not complicated, but without any more specific information about what you already tried no one can give you any advice.

Comment: use service for Timer code & stop service at end of last activity.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variables

```
//counter of time since app started, a background task
private long mStartTime = 0L;
private TextView mTimeLabel;

//handler to handle the message to the timer task
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

Start the timer in onCreate or onStart or your own method (click of button)

```
if(mStartTime==0L){
        mStartTime=SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask,100);
    }
```

timer function

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final long start = mStartTime;
        long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds));
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
    }
};
```

when the app is minimized, pause the timer

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    super.onPause();
}
```

when the app is resumed, resume the timer

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}
```

Comment: @Usman put in the activity where you want to track time, pls accept answer or at least upvote

Comment: mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask); not pausing timer.it keeps running